# Problem when making http request with Axios to a server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, next.js

I am making a get request to jasonplaceholder server to fetch data but when I make the request for some time it shows undefined and then all the data comes , how can I stop this undefined and stop the code processing until the data is fully fetched from the server

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
    import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    export default function Portfolio(){
        const router = useRouter();
    
        const [post,setPost] = useState({})
        console.log("323")
        console.log(router.query.id)
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${router.query.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                setPost(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },[router.query.id])
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>{`userId : ${post.userId}`}</h1>
                <h1>{`id : ${post.id}`}</h1>
                <h1>{`title : ${post.title}`}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Comment: hey, welcome to SO. because the request is asynchronous, the result is not returned immediately, you have to wait until it is fully returned from the API call. In your template, you can add a condition to render something else while the data is being fetched. @kirakok's answer for example

Answer (score 0):

```
const response = await axios('endpoint');

setPost(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition while rendering the code.

Check the below code:

```
<React.Fragment>
            <h1>{`userId : ${post && post.userId}`}</h1>
            <h1>{`id : ${post && post.id}`}</h1>
            <h1>{`title : ${post && post.title}`}</h1>
 </React.Fragment>
```